# Analogue of primitive element theorem for division rings

Tags: ring-theory, division-ring

I was wondering, is the following analogue of the primitive element theorem true for division rings:
Let $R,S$ be division rings of characteristic $0$ such that $R$ is finite dimensional as an $S$-module. Then, there are two elements $a,b \in R$ such that $R=S(a,b)$, the sub-ring generated by elements of $S$ and the two elements $a,b$.

I was mainly trying this for $S=Q$, trying to prove or disprove that if $S=Q$, then such a ring $R$ can be embedded into the quarternions.

(Edit: Added characteristic $0$ condition to avoid the separability issue as pointed by below comment).

Edit: Found out that the second part of my question is not true. We can construct counterexamples of dimension $4$.
...

Comment: Don't forget the separable assumption as $\Bbb{F}_p(x,y,z)/\Bbb{F}_p(x^p,y^p,z^p)$ is generated by no less than 3 elements. For fields the proof goes through $k$-embeddings to the algebraic closure, what will you replace it by ?

Comment: Ok, how about dealing with the characteristic 0 case?

Comment: Ok so the first part is true when S is a perfect field, using properties of CSA's.